# No SICK TiM devices connected! sick_tim320?

Tags: laser, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i use melodic, i try to connect sick tim_320 but i have some problem
[ERROR] [1578729117.004873938]: No SICK TiM devices connected!
[FATAL] [1578729117.004962667]: Failed to init device: 1
[ERROR] [1578729117.004995401]: LIBUSB - device not open
My device worked properly in sopas, have anyone help me resolve this problem
Thank you and i am sorry about my English

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341505/no-sick-tim-devices-connected!-sick_tim320?/) by [trantu080798](https://answers.ros.org/users/50790/trantu080798/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a Tim 315 or 361 because those have an ethernet data output. The 310 and 320 have only an digital OI no data output beside the engeniering USB

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trantu080798](https://answers.ros.org/users/50790/trantu080798/) on 2020-01-11**:
Thank you for your answer. that mean i can't mapping with Tim 320? i'm new so i don't know about it. may be i made a wrong purchase.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-01-12**:
You need an other tim

See the node descrition
http://wiki.ros.org/sick_tim